# Can't see active users on the dashboard after 5+ days of integration

Tags: firebase-analytics

I have successfully integrated with firebase-analytics on android, and I can see all activities on the streamview, but after 5+ days of installation, I still can't see any data on the dashboard.

Is that possible ?

Comment: Did you mean DebugView? Could you see the traffic on DebugView when you turn on debug mode?(See https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview). If you can see real-time events there, you can verify your instruments. Also, can you provide platform, sdk version, OS version?

Comment: @adbitx I didn't try the debugview because the StreamView section was working correctly. The platform is android, and its on all devices

Comment: I'd recommend to use DebugView (it's another option when you use Stream View) since it is at real-time and you can verify exactly what events were uploaded correctly and what errors you may have. Stream view is usually slower (about 30 minutes late). The log in debug mode can also give you information too.

Comment: @adbitx I tried debug view and I can see the traffic, but still I can't see any data in the dashboard for almost 6 days now. Could there be anything missing in the configuration for only DebugView to work

Comment: Interesting. Do you mean like there is nothing at all? Not even first_open event?

Comment: Did you have a project with the same name? Did you delete it and reuse the same package name?

Comment: @adbitx hmm, no its the only project with that package name. It uses Gcm instead for firebase for cloud messaging, but I am not sure that would be the cause since the device already sends out events. But its not showing any accumulated data in the dashboard section

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any other ideas why it is happening. I'd recommend to contact Firebase Support and provide your app information to them. There could be a bug here.

Comment: @adbitx You were absolutely correct, turns out it was a bug on their end